# Python.Pandas : how to select rows where objects does not start with letters 'CASH'

Tags: python, dataframe, data-manipulation

From below dataframe:

[image]

What would be the best way to pull part of dataframe that does not start with 'CASH' in cusip column?

I tried below but neither worked.

```
cleaned_df = df[(df['cusip'][:4] != 'CASH')

cleaned_df = df[(df['cusip'].str.[:4] != 'CASH')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You were close with: `df['cusip'].str.[:4]` but you actually would need `df['cusip'].str[:4]`

Answer (score 0):

... this worked...

```
cleaned_df = df[(df['cusip'].str[:4] != 'CASH')
```

Comment: Alternatively,  you can use `df['cusip'].str.startswith("CASH")` so you don't have to worry about the length